What is schema for XMLReader in Nifi with field has tag attribute?
I have a XML file has structure like:
<docs>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">ac8887db-2105-517f-a858-8c268313eb4b</field>
      <field name="id_account">17</field>
      <field name="changes">{"from":[560342,560678],"to":[560342,560678,496267]}</field>
      <field name="id_mention">f3bac0ab-1a23-59fb-aabf-f3fd8e5f17ea</field>
      <field name="action">TAG</field>
      <field name="id_user">3082</field>
      <field name="status">SUCCESS</field>
      <field name="id_topic">109486</field>
      <field name="created_date">2024-07-25T03:49:48Z</field>
   </doc>
   <doc>
      ...
   </doc>
 ....
</docs>

I want to convert that xml to csv or json, but my schema not working when convert to json (I added the <root></root> tag to wrap the entire xml: <root> <doc> <field> ... </field> </doc> </root>):
My schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "doc",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "fields",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "field",
          "fields": [
            { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
            { "name": "value", "type": "string" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

The result when convert to json:
{
  "doc" : [ {
    "field" : [ "e4295e4f-efc6-58ba-8cef-3ea5f52c6bf8", 17, "{\"from\":true,\"to\":false}", "e8255ed0-f223-519c-87b5-6accd870e534", "RECOVER", 3081, "SUCCESS", 109493, "2024-07-26T14:49:51Z" ]
  }, {
    "field" : [ "48b51392-5581-5aa8-a53b-628507413f8a", 17, "{\"from\":null,\"to\":true}", "e8255ed0-f223-519c-87b5-6accd870e534", "DELETE", 3081, "SUCCESS", 109493, "2024-07-26T14:49:47Z" ]
  }, {
    "field" : [ "c2d5dba8-748a-5e04-b343-c346837a660e", 26, "{\"from\":[],\"to\":[557528,557530,557531,557532]}", "8a5cd0b4-a84b-56d6-9d10-bb6c3e7acefe", "TAG", 3481, "SUCCESS", 4777, "2024-07-26T13:41:41Z" ]
  }, {
    "field" : [ "11f6eedd-19e8-5c16-ac17-e5a4de7cc203", 26, "{\"from\":[557523,557530,557531,557532],\"to\":[557523,557530,557531,557532,557528]}", "55c17b36-7c87-54c8-94ed-b351efb6d62a", "TAG", 3481, "SUCCESS", 4777, "2024-07-26T13:41:38Z" ]
  }, {
    "field" : [ "d1446222-b93a-5c73-bccd-28372f9d2bd4", 26, "{\"from\":[],\"to\":[557523,557530,557531,557532]}", "55c17b36-7c87-54c8-94ed-b351efb6d62a", "TAG", 3481, "SUCCESS", 4777, "2024-07-26T13:41:36Z" ]
}]
}

I want the result of the json file like:
{
        "id":"f521dd5e-c3ed-50cd-926f-0d4fbe95bd23",
        "id_account":17,
        "changes":"{\"from\":[542442,542455],\"to\":[542442,542455,\"542452\"]}",
        "id_mention":"d2205718-c2d0-5971-9941-d59b9e000594",
        "action":"TAG",
        "id_user":3080,
        "status":"SUCCESS",
        "id_topic":100983,
        "created_date":"2023-11-16T09:04:04Z"
}

How to rewrite my schema convert the field has tag with attribute?
